# Can I use auto place anchor strings in DocuSign with Document Visibility on?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a working application where a generic document is defined in the DocuSign template with auto-place anchor strings. In creating the envelope I replace the generic document with a document generated by my application.
A new requirement is to have multiple documents in the template with document visibility turned on so as to control recipients only seeing certain documents.

I have successfully created envelopes replacing the multiple documents with my generated documents using composite templates.
The problem I'm having is with using auto-place anchors. I either receive a response from the API that anchors must be specifically placed on the document or when the recipient receives the document, the process repeatedly loops thru the anchors and never allows the recipient to finish the signing of the document.

The question is can I use auto-place anchors with document visibility?

> The documents I am generating are the same as in the template, but now have been populated with customer information that may change the location of where a signature is needed

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try with multiple composite template, each with 1 document.

See my [article](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/use-template-luke) for more template ideas.